# I have to Transform every line of code that I have written for charts into a class (object oriented) using coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, fusioncharts

Lets say I have 5 Fusion Charts
Most of the charts have same attributes.
I have to pass all this attributes into coffeescript contructor
But how to achieve it?

any sample code would be helpful

Comment: http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Answer (score 0):

Below is a example class declaration that take a parameter and when we call `draw` method it print input `params` on console.

```
class Chart
  constructor: (params) ->
    # initialize your variable 
    # example @foo = params
    @attr = params

  draw: ->
    # access @attr instance variable   
    console.log "your input params is #{@attr}"


 new Chart('this is test params').draw()
```

I highly recommended you first read [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) official guide before start. There are great books available that may help you [The Little Book on CoffeeScript](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/) and [coffeescript-cookbook](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/). And of-course use http://js2.coffee/ site for experiment **js to coffee and vise versa**. Hope it will help you